# Console outputting a certain value - if statement straight after it not working with same value

Tags: c++, struct

```
cout << levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] << endl;
if(levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] == 1.8)
        cout << "pls werk" << endl;
```

So the cout outputs 1.8...yet the if statement does not work.

It's a function in which I'm passing a struct member to using the & pointer.

It's inside this if statement.

```
if(levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] >= 1 & levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] <= 1.8)
{
    levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] = levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] + 0.1;
    chop.play();

    cout << levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] << endl;
    if(levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] == 1.8)
        cout << "pls werk" << endl;
}
```

Calling the function

```
int action(int facing, sf::Sprite& player, sf::View& view, sf::Clock& actionTimer, levelData& levelData, sf::Sound& chop)
```

and the define thing for the function

```
int action(int, sf::Sprite&, sf::View&, sf::Clock&, levelData&, sf::Sound&);
```

Thanks

Comment: `... == 1.8` looks very suspect.

Comment: Why is that? Does == not check for equality?

Comment: cout will round to some precision.  Are you sure it equals _exactly_ 1.8?  Could it be equal to 1.79999999 or 1.80000001, e.g.?

Comment: The only times this variable is changed is once when the game is initialized assigning it an integer.
And then now which adds 0.1 to it so it could only have a max of 1 decimal point.

Comment: @JackWright, Scott is correct, you clearly have some learning to do about floating point arithmetic. Even a simple number like 0.1 is not held **exactly** by your program. Don't compare floating point numbers for equality unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah I've only been doing this for a month or so.

But thankyou, I'll change the variable type.

Comment: @JackWright The easiest way to confirm if it's a floating point issue (which seems highly likely) is to check the value of that variable using your debugger.  If you have to resort to `cout`, look into changing the precision, e.g. `std::cout.precision(12)` before your debug line.  You can possibly avoid this by avoiding floating arithmetic.  Can you simply multiply your starting value by 10, and then add 1 each time?

Comment: I'm going to change it to a double to see if that works.
Probably should have been more careful.

Comment: All I did was change it to a double and now the function reads the spot being hit in the array as 0, however if I go back to my main loop and make it output the value of the array spot on keypress it outputs it as 0.
(Literally all I did was change the variable type now the function is reading a different value from the same spot).   

This is quite frustrating but I'm assuming as soon as I fix whatever is happening here it will work now that it's a double.

Comment: @JackWright That's not a valid assumption, double has more precision that float but not infinitely more. And it's still the case that 0.1 is not exact even as a double. The answer is *don't compare floating point values for equality*. If you feel the need to do this then you are solving whatever problem it is in the wrong way.

Comment: I tried rounding it to 1 decimal place but it still wouldn't work.
I see I have a lot to learn.
I'll stick to integers for now haha.

Thanks for the help though guys.

Comment: @JackWright The only safe way to compare floating precision (including double) is to use epsilon comparisons, i.e. "if |myValue - testValue| < epsilon".  You could do something like `if (Math.abs(levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] - 1.8) < 0.0001)`.  But that's ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in several comments, floating point numbers are a little weird when it comes to equality. This is because, to use a reasonable amount of memory, floating point numbers are not stored exactly, but approximated using increasingly small powers of 2 (i.e. 2^-1 + 2^-2 + 2^-4....). As you might expect, this means that there is a margin of error involved, depending on several factors.

As far as your problem is concerned, it comes down to this: don't use "==" on floating point numbers. Instead, check to see if it is within a margin of error with something like:

```
float acceptableThresholdOfError = .0001;
if(fabs(levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] - 1.8) <= acceptableThresholdOfError)
{ //code }
```

Obviously, the needed precision determines exactly how small the error threshold should be/can be. This way, even if your variable is not a perfect approximation, it can be thought of as such as long as it's "close enough."

Comment: You shold be taking the absolute value on the LHS of your comparision. `fabs(levelData.interactMap[tileHitX][tileHitY] - 1.8) <= acceptableThresholdOfError`

Comment: @john yes, you should. Thanks.